# Search in user's Facebook feed

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to search specific type of feed of the user by using the Graph API with

https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed

The URL normally returns most recent feeds but it is too much data, I just want to search for a specific feed based on some keywords. I have tried

https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?q=SEARCH_KEYWORD

but it does not work (returns empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

With FQL you can pass SQL-Like queries to the Facebook API.